# Edit mobile notifications on desktop client

Tags: mobile, notification

Should there be a setting in the desktop client to let users edit mobile notifications? Is it ok to not allow this in the desktop client and just let them set mobile notification preferences from within the mobile app?

The mobile app is the mobile version of the desktop app, used by the same user. The notifications can be of the following sort: 
- when someone shares a post with the user
- when someone comments on a post shared by the user

A user would want to edit these notification, wanting to turn them on/off for desktop and mobile clients.

Comment: Please clarify.  What is the relationship between the mobile and desktop clients?  What are the notifications for?  Why would a desktop user want to edit them?  Are the desktop and mobile clients used by the same person or is this a team-leader and subordinates arrangement?  We can't help if we don't know...

Comment: @HenryTaylor Added the details in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are taking about a responsive app and shared settings I would agree with Daniel. **Even more so if your notification settings are either ON or OFF regardless of a device.**

In theory, controlling both in any experience makes it convenient (maybe?).

In practice, however, if you are separating settings between mobile and desktop for a specific reason - then *why do you want to clutter your app*?

I understand I might be an exception here, but I just don't see the logic behind having the ability to control settings in one place for an experience on a device I am not currently using.

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer that since both the desktop and and mobile app are interacting with the same service some of the settings are/should be shared by the same user.

No harm is being done by allowing users to modify their mobile settings from the desktop application. Just make sure that everything is clearly labelled.

This is 'valid' for all other settings since the app on mobile and desktop are sharing settings, I am a big fan of syncing setting for the same user but allow for the option for the user to 'un-sync' them.